# Creating border triangle CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make div like this:

[image: attached]

is it possible to make this with css?
if it is, how?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Sometimes a user can legitimately not have any idea on how to do something, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an `:after` psuedo element absolutely positioned and make use of an unoffical CSS triangle.

```
.date {
  background-color: #006;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.date:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-color: #006 transparent transparent transparent
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yonisaqi/2/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Use a `::after` psuedo-element, position it with `absolute`, and move it into position. Then use the typical border tricks to make a triangle - in this case, you'll need left and top borders, I think.

Go and give it a try, then if you're still having problems come back with some code ;)

Comment: Could you please tell me what those typical border tricks are?

Answer (score 2):

That can do a trick :)

http://jsfiddle.net/dxNVa/

```
<div class="hide">
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    margin-left:-20px;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.hide{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add this answer for reference, you don't even need any pseudo-element like `:after` **however** this will make it hard to center the text and you may want to use some image or gradient for the background (which can't go with this solution):

```
div {
 color:white;
 font-size:30px;    
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 line-height:100px;    
 background:blue;
 background-clip:content-box;
 border-left:20px solid blue;       
 border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
 text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5tz6/)

Comment: +1 This is an interesting one but it should be mentioned that this doesn't work on IE8.

Comment: @dystroy thanks, sorry but what kind of feature which makes it not work on IE8? I think other solutions have some kind of higher feature (like `:after`).

Comment: I can't test on IE but I think about [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @KingKing `:after` is supported by IE8 fortunately :)

Comment: @dystroy yes, you're right, looks like it is a fairly new feature.